# Should I start using core data?

Tags: iphone, ios, database, core-data

I have started development of an app which is data reliant. It has a lot of information (using probably only 2 tables) so I am thinking core data is the way to go. However, I hate apps that only work when the user has an internet connection.

So what I would like to do is have saved core data on the device, and only download updates either periodically, on users' request or give them the option to update data when the app has loaded.

Is this the best solution and could someone please point me in the direction of a good blog or tutorial for this.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The topics you ask about are really unrelated.

1. To implement your apps data model, Core Data is a fine solution. The iOS docs and sample code are good. if you need more I'm sure there are various blog posts but I don't have a recommendation. If you run into specific problems/issues there is tons of stuff on SO as well.
2. If you don't want to require a connection that's fine. This has nothing do with core data. It does have to do with apps functional requirements. At a minimum, store the apps current state in the data model and update at whatever interval you like, checking for a connection if that's required. Basically, whatever your app does, if a function requires a connection reflect that in the UI. Everything else should work fine without a connection.

Comment: Thankyou for such a quick, useful and informative reply. So I have the current state of all data as default core data, and then store an sqlite (or JSON??) file on a server which the app will check for updates as an when the code states? This process seems straightforward enough, but how do i test the updating process? Cheers